# How to create simple water drop animation with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation

I wanted to create simple water drop animation how you see in the below pic

[image: water drop]

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: I've tried the example from here http://jsfiddle.net/Oliboy50/QHRaS/5/ but it is not fully what I want.

Comment: Do you have any suggestiones @ddw147?

Comment: if you want faster then try this https://jsfiddle.net/pjLd7L0k/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution.Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLm7d6oy/)

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="drop-outer">
<svg class="drop" viewBox="0 0 40 40" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20"/>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="ripple ripple-1">
  <svg class="ripple-svg" viewBox="0 0 60 60" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="24"/>
  </svg>
</div>
 <div class="ripple ripple-2">
  <svg class="ripple-svg" viewBox="0 0 60 60" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="24"/>
</svg>
 </div>
 <div class="ripple ripple-3">
  <svg class="ripple-svg" viewBox="0 0 60 60" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="24"/>
  </svg>
 </div>
```